# How to filter for a specific set of characters ending with any digit?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column containing values as strings. I need to keep only those that contain one of the following substrings: `|MB1`, `|MB2`, `|MB3`, `|MB4`, `|MB5` and `|MB6`.

My starting point is:

```
select * from table
where column like '%|MB_%';
```

However, this would keep any other row with values such as `|MBa` or others. How do I get rid of them?

P.S. I am using MySQL

Comment: Either you do OR for each one, or use regular expression, or combine LIKE with specific check that character number 4 is one of the digits.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some of them have LIKE extensions, similar to regular expressions...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [regular expression pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html);

```
WHERE `column` REGEXP '\\|MB[1-6]'
```

The pattern `'\\|[1-6]'` can be analysed as follows:

- `\\` is the string-encoding of a literal backslash, which is the regular expression escape character, so that
- `|` is given no special meaning (if not escaped by backslash it would signify alternation, which would lead to an invalid pattern in this case)
- `MB` are literal characters
- `[1-6]` represents a single character within the range `1` through to `6`

Comment: Good explanation for your regex! +1